# webpack IgnorePlugin() on multiple modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

Following the webpack 4.x [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#root), we can ignore plugins with IgnorePlugin() method, but the following example only ignore one module (moment/locales)

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  resourceRegExp: /^\.\/locale$/,
  contextRegExp: /moment$/
});
```

If i want to ignore another module (ex : `react-tooltip/dist/index.es.js`),
is there any way to implement another module to ignore, by passing an array with resourceRegExp or contextRegExp for example ?

I tried that :

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/index\.es\.js$/, /react-tooltip\/dist$/),
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
```

But the file seems to be always present in the bundle

Comment: You're reading documentation for webpack 5. Here's the one for webpack 4 https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/

Comment: Couldn't you just use multiple `new webpack.IgnorePlugin({})`?

Comment: I tried that, but the file seems to appear in the final bundle after testing it (updated code in question)

Comment: have the same issue, have you solved it?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the **filter function** option in IgnorePlugin().

This is how you might do it in **Webpack 5:**

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#using-filter-functions

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
    checkResource(resource, context) {
        const isLocaleFromMomentImport =
                /^\.\/locale$/.test(resource) && /moment$/.test(context);
        const isReactTooltipIndexFile = /^\.\/index\.es\.js$/.test(resource) && /react-tooltip\/dist$/.test(context);

        return (
           isLocaleFromMomentImport ||
           isReactTooltipIndexFile
        );
    },
}),
```

Regarding **Webpack 4**, IgnorePlugin() has also a [**filter function**](https://v4.webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/#using-filter-functions) option, but it's a bit different (checks `resource` and `context` separately). If you are still using that version of webpack you should modify the code from above slightly to match your case... although, I can see that this can be a bit tricky because of the separation of checks...

Answer (score 1):

You could try matching multiple modules in your regex

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
  resourceRegExp: /^\.\/(locale|index\.es\.js)$/,
  contextRegExp: /(moment$|react-tooltip\/dist$)/
});
```

This would match `locale` and `index.es.js` within both `moment` and `react-tooltip/dist`, which isn't exactly the desired solution but may be good enough.